# Searching through a text file java

Tags: java, search, text-files

So I am trying to search through a text file and if the user input is found, it returns the entire sentence including white spaces.But apparently I only get the first string and nothing pass the first string in the sentence. For example if i have a text file called "data.txt" and the contents in the first line is " I am a legend". after user enters "I am a legend" the output after the file is searched is "I". Any help would be appreciated.

```
 public static void Findstr() { // This function searches the text for the    string

    File file = new File("data.txt");

     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" enter the content you looking for");
    String name = kb.next();
    Scanner scanner;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter( ",");

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
            if (lineFromFile.contains(name)) {
                // a match!
                System.out.println("I found " + name);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" cannot write to file " + file.toString());
    }
```

Comment: It would be better if you mention few lines from "data.text "file

Comment: It's okay, I figured out the issue. The issue was at kb.next(). It should be kb.nextLine().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileSearch {

    public void parseFile(String fileName,String searchStr) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            String line = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().toString();
            if(line.contains(searchStr)){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        FileSearch fileSearch = new FileSearch();
        fileSearch.parseFile("src/main/resources/test.txt", "am");
    }

}


test.txt contains:
I am a legend
Hello World
I am Ironman

Output:
i am a legend
i am ironman
```

The above code does case insensitive search. You should use nextLine() to get the complete line. next() breaks on whitespaces.

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()

Comment: How do i go about parsing the file with scanner instead of some string() "am".

Comment: in the above example, am is the search string. You can replace that with anything you want. You can also ask the user input a string for you and pass that as a param in the method.

Comment: I did include scanner as a parameter but then it don't work.   public static        void parseFile(String fileName, Scanner searchStr)
   throws FileNotFoundException {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
         while(scan.hasNext()){
             String line = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().toString();
             if(line.contains(searchStr)){
                 System.out.println(line);
             }
         }
     }

Comment: The arguments of the function parseFile are two String objects. You cannot pass Scanner into it. If you want to pass scanner you will have to change the definition of the method to:

public void parseFile(String fileName,String searchStr, Scanner scanner) throws FileNotFoundException

Comment: Scanner doesn't have text in it. Scanner is a helper class to parse the file. Why can't you define scanner in the parse function?

Comment: I am trying to get the user input then pass that input into the parsefile method. Is that possible?

Comment: Okay so when i do put Scanner as a parameter there is an error at  if(line.contains(searchStr)) << where "searchStr" is the scanner

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.next();` returns the next caracter instead use `Scanner.readLine();`

Edit:
Belive  Scanners use `.nextLine();` not `.readLine();`

Answer (score 0):

When you are scanning your input..

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(" enter the content you looking for");
String name = kb.next();
```

You are accepting only one token. You should accept whole line to be searched as your token using `kb.nextLine()`